# Why does the number of <script> elements affect globally defined functions?

Tags: javascript

I do not understand why the code blocks below are working differently when the buttons are clicked. They both contain two functions that alert different messages, the difference being that in the second example there are separate `<script>` blocks.

In the first example, both buttons alert `Hello too!!!`, but in the second, they alert the individual messages from each function.

The first code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="red">Hello!</button>
  <button id="green">HelloTooo</button>
  <script>
    function func() {
      alert('hello!');
    }
    document.getElementById("red").onclick = func;

    function func() {
      alert('Hello too!!!');
    }
    document.getElementById("green").onclick = func;
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The second code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="red">Hello!</button>
  <button id="green">HelloTooo</button>
  <script>
    function func() {
      alert('hello!');
    }
    document.getElementById("red").onclick = func;
  </script>
  <script>
    function func() {
      alert('Hello too!!!');
    }
    document.getElementById("green").onclick = func;
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Why does it behave in this fashion, when both sets of `func` are defined in the global scope?

Comment: `The difference is the different quantity of script elements` - what?

Comment: @Mjh The first code has one `script` tag, the second one has two `script` tags.

Comment: Why do you give to two different functions the same name? That doesn't make sense for me and it's unclear code...

Comment: There's a half decent question hidden in here - ie why are the `func`s in the separate one not overriding one another like in the first - they're both declared at the global scope.

Comment: @Dimon Your question was a little unclear at first, hence some downvotes from the community.  I've redrafted it a little - I hope thats ok - please [edit] it further if I've changed what you were asking.

Comment: @JamesThorpe, you could change the "green" button event listener to be exactly like the "red" button... the result is the same.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thanks - yes, I had intended to, missed it :)

Comment: BTW, you should avoid global functions. It's bad practice and you won't have problems like that.

Comment: It was just a mistake to give the same name to two functions. But this mistake showed me that i do not have a complete knowledge about objects in javascript. At the moment I have understood myself how to solve this questions. but there is a lot of text (several pages) in this problem solving and I can not spend two hours for translating it from Russian (my native language) to English. But I thank you for your answers

Answer (score 4):

That's because function declarations are hoisted to the top of the enclosing function, or the script in this case. This allows you to call a function before its declaration

```js
func();
function func() {
  console.log('This works!');
}
```

Then, your first example becomes something like

```html
<script>
  /* Function declarations are hoisted to the top */
  function func() {
    console.log('hello!');
  }
  function func() {
    console.log('Hello too!!!');
  }
  /* func is the 2nd one for both calls */
  func();
  func();
</script>
```

However, if you use different scripts, the first script will completely run before running the second one. So function declarations of the second one won't affect the first one.

```html
<script>
  /* Function declarations are hoisted to the top */
  function func() {
    console.log('hello!');
  }
  func();
</script>
<script>
  /* Function declarations are hoisted to the top */
  function func() {
    console.log('Hello too!!!');
  }
  func();
</script>
```

Note it would be different if you just referenced `func` instead of storing its value, because the second script will effectively change the global `func` variable.

```html
<script>
  /* Function declarations are hoisted to the top */
  function func() {
    console.log('hello!');
  }
  setTimeout(function(){
    func(); /* By the time this is called, it will have been altered
               by the 2nd script */
  }, 1e3);
</script>
<script>
  /* Function declarations are hoisted to the top */
  function func() {
    console.log('Hello too!!!');
  }
  setTimeout(function(){
    func();
  }, 1e3);
</script>
```

Comment: Excellent explanation but the button clicks are executed later so doesn't the engine have time to overwrite the func() reference as you stated in your 4th snippet?

Comment: @domenicr The event listener is invoked later, yes. But when you use `.onclick = func` you store the current value of `func` as the event listener, it's not live. If you use `.onclick = function() { func() }` then it will be live.